Не появляется окно с картинкой imshop на Ubuntu, Linux Mint 21.3 Cinnamon. Python, openCV 4.9.0
я изучаю библиотеку openCV (4.9.0) на python и пытаюсь открыть окно с картинкой.
import cv2 as cv
image = cv.imread('image.jpg')
cv.imshow('window', image)

Запускаю код, в консоле ошибок нет, а окно не появляется.
До этого запускал тот же самый код на windows 10, все работало. Сейчас использую Ubuntu, Linux Mint 21.3 Cinnamon

Есть предположение, что у вас картинка не считалась. Почему? Варианты могут быть разные, от неправильнрго регистра в названии файла, до прав доступа к нему.
